# Trigger a scrolling event in a different div when a user scrolls using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two div elements:

When a user scrolls div `#element-A` and `#header-one-target` reaches the top of the containing div the last element (`#animate-hd-b`) in `#element-B` should scroll to the top of the containing div with a nice animation .

Here's the code that I'm working with to start. The code below does something when the window is scrolled not the div.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var offsetTop = $('#animate-hd-b').offset().top,
    outerHeight = $('#animate-hd-b').outerHeight(),
    windowHeight = $(window).height(),
    scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  console.log((offsetTop-windowHeight) , scrollTop);

  if (scrollTop > (offsetTop+outerHeight-windowHeight)){
    alert('you have scrolled to the top!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="element-A" style="background: orange; overflow: auto;">
  <div class="content" style="padding-bottom: 300px;">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <h1 id="header-one-target">Header One</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="element-B" style="background: yellow; overflow: auto;">
  <div class="content" style="padding-bottom: 300px;">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <h1 id="animate-hd-b">Animate This Header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this in jQuery?

Comment: Yep, you capture the distance of the h1 from the top of it's container, and subtract the vertical scroll offset of the parent.  When those reach <= 0, then you perform an animate on the second one, setting the second content's scrollTop to the distance of it's h1 from the top of it's container

Comment: @Taplar Do you have a code example?

Comment: No, because that would require me to write up a full solution, while your question has not shown an attempt to solve this on your own.  This is why I've included the first comment to give you a push towards the direction you should go in.

Comment: @Taplar Please see my code example

Comment: ok, so you have noticed that the logic works when the window was scrolled.  So look at your scroll event listener.  What have you bound on that it listens for scroll events on?  What should that actually be, that scrolls, that you want to listen for events on?

Comment: [Here's](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moaGrG?editors=1010) a demo with some quick adjustments.

Comment: @Taplar  Sorry but I gave you an example which you requested and that I'm showing. Do you have a code example? Where I can see your idea?

Comment: @Shikkediel  Hi Shikkediel, your example isn't working on my side

Comment: Only looked into it shortly before, Jimmy. I've amended it now and posted it as an answer.

Comment: @Jimmy The point of my second comment is that you are not wanting to perform this logic on window scroll.  So binding the scroll event listener on the window is the wrong element to bind on.  You need to bind your scroll event listener on the element you *do* want to listen for events on.  In this case, you are wanting to do something to `element-B` when `element-A` is scrolled, so bind the event handler on element-A.

Comment: @Taplar I understand. But you mentioned that you would not show an example because that would require you to write up a full solution. I showed effort of what I was trying to accomplish by example. But it seems like you never had any intention of showing a code example. I would prefer a code example. But thanks for suggestion

Comment: Depending upon where in a problem a question is at, I will often try to nudge an asker in the direction of a solution.  It is much more benefical if you can work through the issue and solve it yourself.  Questions that show effort but are much more off track, I'll usually post an answer for.  But questions like this which say they want one thing, but are making at least one small mistake, I will absolutely point out the issue in the hopes that the asker takes that point, runs with it, and can come to their own solution.

Comment: @Taplar I understand. But I learn better by code example. But thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 4):

This is really pretty simple. You just keep track of `#header-one-target` and animate
`#animate-hd-b` when `#header-one-target` reaches at the top.

```js
(function($) {
  let $elementA = $('#element-A');
  let $elementB = $('#element-B');
  let $headerOneTarget = $('#header-one-target');
  let $animateHdB = $('#animate-hd-b');
  let isScrollAtTop = true;
  $elementA.scroll(function() {
    if (isScrollAtTop && $headerOneTarget.offset().top < 5) {
      isScrollAtTop = false;
      $elementB.animate({
        scrollTop: $elementB.scrollTop() + $animateHdB.offset().top
      });
    } else if ($elementA.scrollTop() < 5) {
      isScrollAtTop = true;
      $elementB.animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#element-A {
  background: orange;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 60vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#element-B {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 40vw;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.content-vh100 {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="element-A">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Scroll</p>
    <p>to</p>
    <p>header</p>
    <p>one</p>
    <h1 id="header-one-target">Header One</h1>
    <div class="content-vh100"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="element-B">
  <div class="content">
    <p>to</p>
    <p>animate</p>
    <p>following</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <h1 id="animate-hd-b">Animate This Header</h1>
    <div class="content-vh100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it builds up a queue of animations when using a browser with smooth scrolling, which makes the element on the right to get stuck.

Comment: Customize the if-condition to your needs, keep flags to avoid queue buildup.

Comment: @MunimMunna Very helpful. Is there animation be called more than once? For example if I scroll down the header reaches the top. The animation activates. But if I Scroll back up, and scroll down again The header does not animate. I know this is silly on my part but I'm just curious why it doesn't animate (scroll to the top ) again.

Comment: @Jimmy I didn't get your query, the header does not animate because it's already at the top, isn't it? if you want it to go back to original position when scrolled to the top, just add another if-block.

Comment: Check updated answer, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not to nitpick but if you scroll the right window down a bit first and then scroll the left one, if it is before the point where the header is then the window on the right actually scrolls to the top as well. This makes it scroll twice in opposite directions shortly after one another.

Comment: @MunimMunna Is there a suggested fix to the scroll issue that Shikkediel noticed?

Comment: What issue? I don't see any issues.

Answer (score 3):

Some conditions were added that should prevent unnecessary animations and queueing (which tends to happen when listening for `scroll` and animating `scrollTop`). It keeps track of the scroll direction and won't start animating when the element on the right has already reached its position.

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moaGrG)

```js
var sin = $('#element-A'),
dex = $('#element-B'),
peg = sin.scrollTop();

sin.scroll(function() {

  var way = sin.scrollTop(),
  rate = Math.round(sin.find('h1').position().top),
  area = dex.scrollTop(),
  turf = Math.round(dex.find('h1').position().top),
  down = way > peg;
  peg = way;

  // conditions for scrolling down

  if (rate < 0 && down && turf) {
    dex.not(':animated').animate({scrollTop: area+turf}, 700);
  }

  // scrolling up

  if (!down && area) {
    dex.not(':animated').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 700);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body > div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

#element-A {
  background: orange;
}

#element-B {
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  padding-bottom: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="element-A">
  <div class="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <h1 id="header-one-target">Header One</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="element-B">
  <div class="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <h1 id="animate-hd-b">Animate This Header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case the elements are differently positioned in the target environment, using `position()` is a more straightforward approach than `offset()` because the latter is relative to the document. The former (used here) is relative to its own parent element and should work independent of its position.

Comment: This is helpful I'm curious. Is there anyway to reverse the animation when the user scrolls the opposite direction? I only ask because the animation is called only once when I scroll.

Comment: No problem, I've added it to the [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moaGrG). Let me know if that is the intented behaviour, I'll only edit the answer if it is (and maybe you have more feedback before that).

Comment: I'm curious. What if I had multiple headers on the left `<h1 id="header-one-target">Header One</h1>` , `<h1 id="header-two-target">Header Two</h1>` and based off of the position of the headers I could animate the "Animate Header on the right? Any suggestions? Would I need to create multiple conditions?

Comment: Maybe you could be more specific what should happen to the element on the right... but [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PgNYzx) is an example where the second target changes the its text color.

Comment: Great example.  I'd like the second header `<h1 id="header-two-target">Header Two</h1>` reaches near the top, I'd like the position of the Animate This Header text to be offer from the top maybe 100 pixels something like a margin top 100. My goal is that `Animate This Header` moves a different position based off of when Header One, Header two and so on reaches the top.

Comment: I've worked on a more [elaborate example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OGNzav) but I'll have to give it another review to see if there aren't any glitches (I like to be thorough).